# Is it possible to make kit kat action bar to work in android version 2.2?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner for android development. Recently I created one app and in that app I used the action bar. And when I tested my app with Android 4.4.2, it is ok. But when I tested with android version 2.2, there cannot load the action bar. Is this because of compatible problem? If so how can I use this action bar for android 2.2? Do I need to change my source code?

The following is my code declaration for action bar in Manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.sample.android.ScreenSlideActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Action Bar Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html):

> The [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

Specifically, the [AppCompat v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7) part of the support library adds support for the Action Bar to all Android 2.1+ devices, including features such as the [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar). As it is maintained by Google, it stays up to date with new releases of Android.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called `ActionBarSherlock` that provides action bar on `2.x`

Please go through these web sites and have a basic idea about it

http://actionbarsherlock.com/
http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarinactionbarsherlock

Thanks and regards

Comment: use some tags provided by stackoverflow for you answer, it make easy to read for others.